# Understanding pseudocode for binomial RV generation

Tags: probability, random-variables

I am trying to understand the following pseudocode used to generate a binomial RV with parameters n,p. I'm not sure what is going on, and I would appreciate if someone could describe what is happening.

Pseudocode:

```
T = 0;

for i = 1:n

    U = Unif(0,1)
    if U <= p
       T = T + 1;
    end if
end for

output T
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U is generated from (0,1) interval as a uniform distribution.  Binomial distribution is characterised by $n$ number of individual bernoulli trials. In a bernoulli trial, p is the probability of success and (1-p) is the probability of failure. So for n independent trials, you pick a number from (0,1) interval, if is less than p, you increment the number of successful trials, otherwise (n-t) would be the number of failures.  That is what this code is telling you.

Thanks

Satish